# Combinations for Screen lock For iPhone / Android

Tags: combinatorics, applications

I was wondering if there was a general for formula to calculate the combination of the password lock for the current smart phones

[image]

The following is the condition

1. We must use four nodes or more to make a pattern at least.
2. Once anode is visited, then the node can't be visited anymore.
3. You can start at any node.
4. A pattern has to be connected.
5. Cycle is not  allowed.

If using 4 as the minimum string for the password with 9 nodes , the result is 389112.

Is there anyway to estimate the number of combinations for 16 nodes, 25 nodes and so on?

Comment: The number 389112 shows up exactly once at the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, at http://oeis.org/A160743 where it's $8P_7(n)$, Legendre polynomial of order 7. I doubt it's related, just thought I'd save others the trouble of consulting OEIS.

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37167/combination-of-smartphones-pattern-password) is closely related. It's very nearly a duplicate, including the same image and wording, except it doesn't ask about the generalization to larger grids.

Comment: Note that the answer $389112$ is obtained if the rules specified in [this other duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128423/9-dots-possible-combinations-problem) are assumed. If these are the intended rules, the present problem description is incomplete.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am just learning about Legendre Polynomials and I am glad of you mentioning it. I did not know that Legendre Polynomials will be useful for these types of problems.

Comment: @dii, did you see where I wrote, "I doubt it's related"?

Comment: @GerryMyerson way to spoil Legendre polynomials then.

Comment: how Legendre Polynomials  and Legendre's differential equation can solve this problem?

Comment: As @Gerry wrote, they most likely can't. It's most likely just a coincidence.

Answer (score -1):

Since each dot can be the starting point for the pattern, the number of possibilities are as follows:

1. 4 dots combination (since this is the minimum required): 9 dots (starting points) ^ (raise to the power) 4 = 6,561 patterns
2. 5 dots combination: 9 dots ^ 5 = 59,049 patterns
3. 6 dots combination: 9 dots ^ 6 = 531,441 patterns
4. 7 dots combination: 9 dots ^ 7 = 4,782,969 patterns
5. 8 dots combination: 9 dots ^ 8 = 43,046,721 patterns
6. 9 dots combination: 9 dots ^ 9 = 387,420,489 patterns

Total possible number of patterns = 435,847,230 patterns

Comment: That's not right. The dot sequence must be *connected*.