# What are the odds of cracking a cellphone pattern-lock?

Tags: probability

In case someone don't know what a pattern lock is, they are like this:

[image: example of a pattern lock]

I am curious on the probability of randomly cracking one of these 'passwords', given that the length of the grid is `3x3` and that we know the *pattern length* (e.g number of lines).

Also, you may or not noticed but the pattern can go in both `+` and `x` directions.

**Note:** we can have multiple lines that go to a single dot, but we can never draw a line above another line (I think some apps allow this, but for this question lets assume we will not).

Comment: Can patterns be of any length (i.e., 1 or more dots)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120655/what-is-the-entropy-of-androids-dot-password-system

Comment: @sacohe the minimum is connecting 2 dots, the maximum however, was left blank because the answers I want to be like a function that you put one number here and then everything is done using that number sorry my englishç

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of [Combination of smartphones' pattern password.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/37167/242)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer arrived at the end in sunflower's link, 389112 is actually incorrect. It doesn't take into account patterns connect via 2 steps along a line, or a peg jump if the middle point is already used. The correct answer thus becomes 766752. Here's the explanation given by Yoyo Zhou, a Google engineer, along with his algorithm :-

http://www.quora.com/How-many-combinations-does-Android-9-point-unlock-have

Comment: Actually 389112 is correct. It is impossible to draw patterns like '1-8-2' since the middle dot should be also connected. (Swiping fingers like '1-8-1-2' does not help.) I too got 'incorrect' solution 766752 without considering that and got 389112 after fixed.

Comment: '1-8-2' is not a peg jump. An example of a peg jump would be '2-1-3'. Also, though older phones initially didn't allow moves like '1-8-2', it's valid in almost all new phones now. I know for a fact that it is, in mine.

Comment: So can '1-8-2' be done without doing '1-8-5-2'? (My phone can't do this.) And the result 389112 of course concerns those moves. ('1-2-3', '2-1-3', '2-3-1' are valid and different, but '1-3-2' can't be done.)